# Dehydrate Jaggery

Tags: dehydrating, moisture

I want to use jaggery powder in a recipe which is meant to be long stored. I am unable to find how to dehydrate jaggery block and then form powder to remove moisture content from jaggery. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the storage time of powder vs block jaggery is about the jaggery itself and does not have to translate to different storage time for a recipe made with it